# SQL specific count query

Tags: php, mysql

```
"SELECT COUNT (one, two, three, four, five)  FROM $this->tablename where username='$username' and one='Not done' and two='Not done' and three='Not done' and four='Not done' and five='Not done'"
```

I want to count the amount of times the value for "Not done" is found for row "username" for the columns one, two, three, four and five. This query however, does not work. I have no clue to make it work, but I do have a feeling that this query could be way shorter.

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: This kind of problem is often symptomatic of poor design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT (one='Not done')
     + (two='Not done')
     + (three='Not done')
     + (four='Not done')
     + (five='Not done')
     AS num_not_done
FROM $this->tablename 
where username='$username'
```

The expression `(column='Not done')` will return `1` or `0`. So you can just sum the results to get the count of matches.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel The result of this query is already the amount? Or do I still have to add something. Because I'm getting blank result on my page.

Comment: @Vitalynx - It works here: http://rextester.com/PNQ63046 - So check your code around the query.

Comment: The problem is with your PHP side. The pure `mysql` side of it is fine.